# PostgreSQL Deployment Script Stalls

Tags: sql, bash, postgresql, shell, debian

I have a bash shell deployment script (linode stackscript) which runs when I deploy my debian 6.0 server. The script runs as root and the script is as follows:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install postgresql postgresql-contrib pgadmin3

passwd postgres
su - postgres
psql -c "ALTER USER postgres WITH PASSWORD 'changeme'" -d template1
su - postgres
createdb mytestdb
psql mytestdb
```

I have two problems:

Firstly, when I run each line manually through shell it works, but when I run it as the stackscript it runs the line *passwd postgres* but nothing after it.

Secondly, when I run the line *passwd postgres* it asks me to put in my password manually. Is there any way I can put it in as a variable in the shellscript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`passwd` is meant to be used interactively.
The proper command to change a password in a batch is `chpasswd`.

Example:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo 'postgres:newpassword' | chpasswd
```

Also note that the way your script does `su - postgres` does not look like it's normally done in non-interactive mode.
Better do: `su -c 'command1; command2...' - postgres`